# Is the RMSE of a regression related to the standard error of its regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance

Is the root mean square error (RMSE) of a regression related to the standard error of its regression coefficients? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Under the classical setting of the multiple regression, we know that
$$
E||y-\hat{y}||_2^2 = {\rm tr}\big[\sigma^2 (I - X(X^{\rm T} X)^{-1} X^{\rm T})\big] = \sigma^2 (n - {\rm rank}(X)),
$$
where the last equality holds from a trace of an idempotent matrix. Also, 
$$
{\rm Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2 (X^{\rm T} X)^{-1}.
$$
From the facts above, it can be said that if covariates are more correlated, then (1) the rank of $X$ is small so that the RMSE gets larger, and (2) $\hat{\beta}$ would have more variation from multicolinearity.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: The rank of X will not be lowered by multicollinearity unless the multicollinearity is perfect, although the condition number of X will be adversely affected.